# Reading in config data throws error in jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using react in conjunction Jest and enzyme. My unit tests were working as desired until I added a config.json that lives in src/config/config.js and it appears like so:

```
{
    "appName": "Mystery",
    "clients": {
       "api1": "http://localhost:8082",
       "api2": "http://localhost:8083",
       "api3": "http://localhost:8084"
    },
}
```

I import this file in my client folder that I use for network requests in this manner:

```
import CONFIG from '../../config/config.json';

    const api = new Client(CONFIG.clients.api1);
```

Now when I run npm test I get this error on all my files that use that specified api:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'api1' of undefined

After some google foo.... I'm stymied. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if additional details are required.

Comment: Did you see if `CONFIG` is even being exported/imported correctly? That's a default import, you would usually need to `export default {...}` in your config file

Comment: It's a config file that is registered on npm start and other npm scripts so I'm not using the export default. It's registered successfully on npm start, but not when executing npm test

Comment: If it's a config file that just declares an object, you'd probably need `config = require('../../')`. import/export would require a module.exports or default export.

Comment: That stopped npm start from working and introduced a number of errors with npm test.

Comment: Solved the issue, but thank for your help Yuji. Ended up having to update the __mocks__ to include the config.json

Comment: Your mocks affected the import? Strange.. well glad you solved.